# How to re-run the main method after pressing a key

Tags: c#, methods, console-application

How do I make it so when I press for example space that my main method is called again?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int r = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            int q = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            int w = rnd.Next(0, 9);

            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.WriteLine(q);
            Console.WriteLine(w);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a `while(true)` around the code.

Comment: @Jon How do i do this? I am VERY new to coding

Comment: In that case you definitely should be reading introductory tutorials instead of asking on SO. The structure of the site is not well-suited to explaining the very basics which are covered pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @user2979104 For more info on `while` look here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use an infinite loop or a loop that checks wether or not to continue:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool again = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (again)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int r = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                int q = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                int w = rnd.Next(0, 9);

                Console.WriteLine(r);
                Console.WriteLine(q);
                Console.WriteLine(w);
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                    again = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the loop continues until the Q key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You need do

```
while (true) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int r = rnd.Next(0, 9);
    int q = rnd.Next(0, 9);
    int w = rnd.Next(0, 9);

    Console.WriteLine(r);
    Console.WriteLine(q);
    Console.WriteLine(w);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop that will check for key presses every time. If the space key is pressed, the loop will continue. If not, it will break.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int r = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            int q = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            int w = rnd.Next(0, 9);

            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.WriteLine(q);
            Console.WriteLine(w);
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
            if (keyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course, you can change the key to any key you want.